# Why is Fetch Undefined?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am copying a code DIRECTLY from discord.js guide to send a direct message to myself (and only myself) through my bot.

```
module.exports = {
     callback: async(client) => {

        const user = await client.users.fetch('503965897203908609');
        user.send('content');

    }
}
```

here's the relevant code. and when I run the command, I get

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')

WHY

Comment: It means that `client.users` is `undefined`.

Comment: `client` is not actually a Client instance, make sure you pass in a valid client object as a parameter for `callback`

Comment: Please explain how

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the callback function showed in the question? Some times, you might be passing some different arguments there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Because your client.users is undefined, if we try to access a property on undefined it will throw an error.

as to why `client.users` is undefined, that would be something which requires more code to look at

Comment: you could add a dummy client object here or check for existence before executing your code for example

if(client.users) client.users.fetch(some-data)

Comment: it turns out the client is defined, but users is not defined. I don't know how to change that